# Creating three different models through a single resource in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

I have 4 resources as follows in my rails 3.2 application.

- GarageAdmin
- SuperAdmin
- Garage
- RegisterGarage

Now a part of my application has to work like this,

- The SuperAdmin can create GarageAdmin via a resource RegisterGarage.
- A GarageAdmin has_one Garage and a Garage belongs_to GarageAdmin.
- The RegisterGarage stores some other information for admin use.

  Now what I am trying to accomplish is that when the SuperAdmin creates a GarageAdmin, the Garage corresponding to that GarageAdmin will also get created simultaneously through that RegisterGarage resource only.

I am calling two callbacks in the RegisterGarage resource:

- `before_create :pass` . This will generate a random password for GarageAdmin
- `before_save :garage` . This will create a new Garage for the just created GarageAdmin and assign a name to it.

Till now I am able to create a GarageAdmin if I remove the `before_save :garage`. But I get an error `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` when I use `before_save :garage` in RegisterGarage.

Can anyone guide me if I am doing it the right way and also guide me how to implement that.

I am using mongoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association name is `garage`, and your callback is also named `garage`.  This means (assuming the callback is listed in your model after the association) that every time you try to reference your `garage` association, you are actually calling the callback method - this is likely the cause for the error.

Try changing your callbacks to something different (and more descriptive) like `init_password`, `init_garage`.  Also, if the new Garage should only be created when the GarageAdmin is first created, it should be a `before_create` callback, not `before_save`. Otherwise, a new Garage will be created every time the GarageAdmin is updated.

Comment: Thanks PinnyM very much don't know how I missed on that.